# If an event "ends on" a day, does the day constitute a part of the event?

Tags: time

If I loaned someone some item, and I told them that their possession of the item "ends on 2014/12/31", would 2014/12/31 be part of the time that they still have possession of the item?

Or, say if I were to hold a contest, and I said that contest "ends on 2014/12/31", would 2014/12/31 still be a date where the contest is still being held?

What's the more common expectation of the phrase?

Comment: In most of and general cases yes. But when it comes to financial and legal stuff, it varies.

Comment: The best way to prevent any misunderstandings is to specify the precise day, hour and minute when the auction ends, the item has to be returned, no more entries will be accepted, or the bankers will be executed. Otherwise, people have a tendency to interpret lack of clarity to their own advantage: this is apt to lead to arguments, library fines and blood feuds.

Comment: "I went to the park on Friday" means 'sometime on Friday' and so is imprecise.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Apparently you're one of the lucky ones that gets Fridays. And parks.

Comment: @Erik Kowal "one of the lucky ones 'who' or 'that' gets fridays". which one is more appropriate or say correct?

Comment: @Codeek - Either is fine. The 'who' version is in a more formal register. Here, 'that' is more appropriate to the conversational tone I was aiming for.

Comment: @ErikKowal Being an old geezer like Edwin or me has its compensations. The downside is that you get roped in to play Father Christmas.

Comment: @WS2 I've got the sack. HxNy (well, man flu at least) is not a gift the kids would want to receive.

Comment: @Erik Shouldn't that be getses?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sympathies. Try and get it over before the real Father Christmas arrives!

Comment: @WS2 Thank you. Though I'm telling Catherine that he's coming every night at the moment; that's why the tot of whisky keeps disappearing. I don't think it's those M & S fairies.

Comment: Ok, guys, get over it!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, normally that last day is part of the loan agreement or contest.

This is how my library does it: an item due back on Monday can be returned or renewed any time on Monday with no fine. If returned or renewed on Tuesday, a fine is given.

For avoidance of doubt, give an explicit time for the loan to end, or use clear language explicitly stating how the last day is handled. If you check, you may find this in the small print for loans and contests.