# Which on is correct? “Closed your account by/to 30/11/2020”

Tags: prepositions

I've closed your account **by** 30/11/2020

I've closed your account **to** 30/11/2020

Comment: What is the sentence intended to mean? The first might be correct in some contexts, while the second doesn't make much sense with a future date.

Comment: I suspect that you actually mean "I have closed your account _with effect from_ 30//11/2020. This would mean that the account is, technically, open for the next few days but will close completely at the end of the month. Is this what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 2):

> I've closed your account by 30/11/2020
>
> I've closed your account to 30/11/2020

Neither of these makes sense. They are both incorrect.

You could say

*I've closed your account **until** 30/11/2020.*  This means that you have closed it temporarily and you will reopen it on 30/11/2020.

or you could say

*I've closed your account (effective) **from** 30/11/2020.* This means that the account was/will be closed on 30/11/2020. There is no indication that it will ever be reopened.

Answer (score -1):

Given some modifications the two sentences can be made sense of.

- I've closed your account, *and I'll reopen* it by 30/11/2020. (*This means "I'll reopen it not later than 30/11/2020*)
- I've closed your account *for a period* to *end* 30/11/2020. (*The period will end precisely on 30/11/2020, at a given time on that day, depending on how days are counted.*)
  [If an event "ends on" a day, does the day constitute a part of the event?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/215970/349876)

Comment: The interpretation of the second sentence is fairly obvious, but it is less than clear what the reason is for interpreting the first one in the way that is proposed here.

Comment: @jsw29 "By" must be interpreted as "until some time by 30/11/2020", supposing the main idea in "by" (possibly before) has been understood by the user of the incorrect sentence.